# Mysql an index with 8 columns

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing

We have a table that contains 1,000,000 records.
This table has a key on 8 string columns-

```
CREATE TABLE "Table" (
   "pk1" varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
   "pk2" varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
   "pk3" varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
   "pk4" varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
   "pk5" varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
   "pk6" varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
   "pk7" varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
   "pk8" varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
   "combined_pk" varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
   "more_data1" int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   "more_data2" int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   "more_data3" int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   "more_data4" int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   KEY "MainKey" ("pk1","pk2","pk3","pk4","pk5","pk6","pk7","pk8")
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=ascii
```

Not all columns are filled, and frankly, in most of the rows, only 3-4 columns are field.

This Key is being used in order to prevent duplication in the table for the same key.
The reason this is not Unique/PK is because the user can configure that he is ok with duplication.

This table is 80% read, 20% write.

I know that complicate composite indexes can be inefficient.
Do you think it's better to create a new column - 
A concatenation of all the pk's columns (filed via a trigger)
And this new column will be indexed as a varchar(200) ?

Or just leave it like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

If the choice is between the index with eight columns and putting the same data in a single column, then leave the index as it is!  It is hard to imagine queries where the single-concatenated-column index would be useful.  The 8-column index could be useful for many queries.  Updates/inserts with triggers *and* indexes will be slower than updates/inserts only with indexes.

If you are trying to ensure that the eight columns have no duplicates, you need `unique` rather than `key` (duplicate `NULL` values are allowed, so these will not be a problem).

If you want these 8 columns to be a composite primary key, then I would suggest declaring them to be `NOT NULL` and finding declaring all 8 to be a primary key.  That said, I am a fan of auto-incremented integer primary keys.  If you used such a primary key, then a unique index on the 8 columns would suffice.